# FInd similar patterns in a row using Awk or SED

Tags: perl, awk, sed

Need some help here
I have file which has multiple rows, Something like below

```
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+44+1++20160218'
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+44+1++20160218'
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401'FST+S:KSSSSS+2'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+44+1++20160218'
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401'
```

I am trying to get all the segments within a row which begins with **FSR**
so results should be something like this, add pipe every time its finds a FSR, since they are constant on where they would occur in row. so i am not able to use cut here, in short FSR may come in beginning , middle or in the end of the row

```
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401' | **FSR**+S:KSSSSS+44+1++20160218'
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401' | **FSR**+S:KSSSSS+44+1++20160218'
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401' | **FSR**+S:KSSSSS+44+1++20160218'
'**FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401'
```

Additionally, this is the code, i had written in perl, thinking if this could be could be done in simple way

#!/usr/bin/perl

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
chomp($filename);

open(FILE,$filename);
my ($FSR);

while(my $data = <FILE>) {
        #print $data;
        ($FSR) = "";
        if($data =~ /('FSR.*?)(.*?)(\')/) {
                $FSR = "$1,$2";
        }
print "$FSR\n";
}
 close(FILE);
```

Please help

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49012475/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Comment: well, i have written my code and it seems to ending up with 1st result, here is it, hence this questions, feel free, if you still think the question doesn't stand a chance, Thanks    #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
chomp($filename);

open(FILE,$filename);
my ($FSR);

while(my $data = <FILE>) {
  #print $data;
        ($FSR) = "";
        if($data =~ /('FSR.*?)(.*?)(\')/) {
                $FSR = "$1,$2";
        }
print "$FSR\n";
}
 close(FILE);

Comment: please, edit your post instead of posting code as a comment

Comment: Now that you've shown your code, I'm more confused: didn't you say you wanted to add a pipe symbol.  Your code seems to be attempting to add a comma.

Comment: Either ways i am fine, i tried with comma, though, thanks for notifying

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

The following one-liner would seem to address your problem as described:

```
$ sed -i -e 's/FSR/ | FSR/g' YOURFILE
```

Is there something more to this or is that what you were looking for?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18952023)

Comment: This an answer to the question in this post.  The question 'what am I missing?' is directed at @SandeepKumar because the fact that such a simple answer seems to be all they're seeking potentially means that I don't fully understand the scope of their question---it's a request that they elaborate.

Comment: That isn't clear. You should edit to make the answer clearer and to also explain what the code does and why it fixes the problem. If you want someone to elaborate, comment on their question/answer.

Comment: The result give me the entire line, rather then 2 segments as confirmed above                     **FSR**+S:KSSSSS+20+14++20120401' | **FSR**+S:KSSSSS+44+1++20160218'

Comment: You need to edit your question to make it clear what defines a "segment".  Is it the apostrophe?